# Upgrading angular 2.0.0 to 2.4.x

Tags: angular, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade my Angular 2.0.0 application to 2.4.8 i used following link guides https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates. but i get some error.

**Old dependencies**

```
dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"@types/node": "^6.0.38",
"angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.10",
"angular2-universal": "~2.0.10",
"angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.0.10",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^1.0.6",
"aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"css": "^2.2.1",
"css-loader": "^0.25.0",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^0.9.0",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"jquery": "^2.2.1",
"preboot": "^4.5.2",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"ts-loader": "^0.8.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^1.12.14",
"webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
"webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.21"
}
```

**New dependencies**

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
"@angular/core": "2.4.8",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
"@angular/http": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
"@angular/router": "3.4.8",
"@types/node": "^7.0.5",
"angular2-platform-node": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-universal": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
"angular2-universal-polyfills": "~2.1.0-rc.1",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.3",
"aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.11",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
"css": "^2.2.1",
"css-loader": "^0.26.1",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
"expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
"file-loader": "^0.10.0",
"isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
"jquery": "^3.1.1",
"preboot": "^4.5.2",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"rxjs": "5.2.0",
"style-loader": "^0.13.0",
"to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
"ts-loader": "^2.0.1",
"typescript": "^2.0.0",
"url-loader": "^0.5.7",
"webpack": "^2.2.1",
"webpack-externals-plugin": "^1.0.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.10.0",
"webpack-merge": "^3.0.0",
"zone.js": "^0.7.7"
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'fetch-data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

**Error Log**

```
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN extract-text-webpack-plugin@1.0.1 requires a peer of webpack@^1.9.11 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-universal-polyfills@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of rxjs@~5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
npm WARN Angular2Spa@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN Angular2Spa@0.0.0 No license field.
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ivisual\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.4
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\ivisual\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ng20\ng20\node_modules\.staging\lodash-f67ffa4b\fp\bindAll.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall lstat

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ivisual\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ng20\ng20\node_modules\.staging\lodash-f67ffa4b\fp\bindAll.js'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\ivisual\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ng20\ng20\node_modules\.staging\lodash-f67ffa4b\fp\bindAll.js'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ivisual\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ng20\ng20\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: did you try cache clean?

Comment: @suraj i've cleaned node_modules folder if you mean that

Comment: Its a dependency mismatch. your `extract-text-webpack-plugin` requires a lower version of `webpack` and `angular-universal` also requires a lower version of `rxjs`. Check if it works with lower versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i changed my package.json as below and it worked.

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.5",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular2-platform-node": "~2.0.11",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "angular2-universal": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "angular2-universal-patch": "^0.2.1",
    "angular2-universal-polyfills": "^2.1.0-rc.1",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^2.0.0",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^1.0.17",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "css": "^2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.25.0",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.1",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^0.0.7",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-rc",
    "file-loader": "^0.9.0",
    "html-loader": "^0.4.4",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "preboot": "^4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "typescript": "^2.2.1",

    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.0",

    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.12.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^0.14.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  }
```

Comment: I've been tracking these f* dependencies for 2 hours now. You saved my day, thanks!